# Save customized survey list as template

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, custom-form, survey, survey-list

I have a survey list in which I have added redirecting to thank you page on finish button. [From this blog](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/sharepoint-survey-redirect-to-thank-you-page-on-finish.html)

I need to save this list as template so that whenever user creates new survey I don't have to customize this list to add thank you page.

Is this possible? And if yes how can I achieve this?

I tried to save this list as template but the issue is when I create new form for "NewForm.aspx" and customize it, it creates as static HTML of the survey's new form and when I tried to create a new survey from this template customized new form appears with static HTML of with the previous surveys question. New questions do not appear on the customized form.

Thank you in advance...!

Comment: Would suggest you to create a custom list, keep just one `Title` column and check if this issue appears?

Comment: Hello @AhmadZia I tried as you told and found the same issue.

Comment: Sorry @Rahul, could you brief when you saved the custom list (with just one Title column) as template and created the list using that template, did it create the new list? or did you get an error?